# How should we handle the flash tag?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

**Update: The split is done. Whats still on the ToDo list is the blacklisting of [flash](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flash).**

There was/is some inconsistency with the *flash* tag. It meant either:

- To flash a new ROM
- Adobe Flash
- The camera's flash

I suggest the following split:

- *flashing*: For flashing a device
- *adobe-flash*: For Adobe Flash
- *camera-flash*: For a questions regarding a camera flash

Which leaves the question for what *flash* should be a synonym? I think that the best choice would be *adobe-flash*.

Comment: definitely a good idea

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good spot, there's a definite need to split those up.

"**adobe-flash**" and "**camera-flash**" absolutely should be split up, and they sound like the right names for the tags.

I'd say that "**flashing**" as a bare word still has scope for confusion (and also some slightly less savoury connotations). Can't think of the exact phrase, but I'm thinking it could be something like "**rom-flashing**" "**os-flashing**" or "**hardware-flashing**".

However for the old "**flash**" tag, it doesn't really make sense to have it as a synonym of any of those (the fact that we'll have to split it into three separate tags, already makes me think it's not going to be a true synonym of any of those). I'd suggest instead that "flash" should be removed and blacklisted to stop anyone recreating it. Then anyone trying to use a "flash" tag will get the three above tags as suggestions and won't be able to use a confusing "flash" tag.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware that this is possible. Blacklisting *flash* and changing *flash* to *adobe-flash* should be the next step. But maybe *flashing* should become a synonym for *(rom-flashing|hardware-flashing|device-flashing)*. Not sure which one would be best :)

Comment: I like `rom-flashing`.

Comment: `rom-flashing` works for me.

Comment: I merged `flash` to -> `adobe-flash` and `flashing` to -> `rom-flashing`.  A dev will have to blacklist `flash` for us.

Comment: @BryanDenny [flash] is a synonym of [adobe-flash] now...that doesn't seem to go along with a request to blacklist it...?

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff I did that until it could be blacklisted such that it wouldn't create the flash tag anymore

Comment: I've undone the synonym -- if `flash` fades away it doesn't need to be blacklisted unless it comes back.