# Merge firmware and rom?

Tags: discussion, synonym-request, tag-cleanup

Just found the [firmware](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/firmware) tag (x38), where questions mostly refer to either [rom](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rom) (x78) or [custom-rom](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/custom-rom) (x141).

Suggestion:

1. remove the [firmware](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/firmware) from those questions already tagged [custom-rom](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/custom-rom)
2. merge [firmware](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/firmware) into [rom](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rom)
3. make [firmware](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/firmware) a synonym to [rom](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rom)

Though there's one more thing to consider: [firmware](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/firmware) may be ambiguous, as it could as well refer to [radio-firmware](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio-firmware) (x6). How do we deal with ambiguous tags in general, and especially in this case?

**EDIT:** as per suggestion from GAThrawn (to check [What's the intended purpose of the 'radio' tag?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/887/whats-the-intended-purpose-of-the-radio-tag)), those questions relating to radio-firmware *and* radio-firmware itself could be merged into [cellular-radio](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cellular-radio) in this process.

Comment: While not quite the same thing, I can't help thinking that some of the ROM/Custom-ROM/Firmware thing also overlaps with the Stock/Vanilla Android tags: http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/428/merge-stock-stock-android-vanilla-define-stock-android Also see Radio http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/887/whats-the-intended-purpose-of-the-radio-tag

Comment: @GAThrawn The radio tag does no longer exist (stated in the linked meta). Following that, radio-firmware should be merged to [tag:cellular-radio] then. As for stock etc.: Looks like the outcome of my suggestion meets the results from there, as far as I understand it.

Comment: I guess this got obsolete due to [Rename the 'firmware' tag to 'device-firmware' and make 'firmware' a synonym](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/1410/16575), and thus should be closed (alternatively: `status-declined` :)

Answer (score 4):

[firmware](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/firmware) could relate not just to the system firmware, but - as you already noted - also the radio/wifi/camera/etc. firmware. That prevents me from liking the idea. [In the past, if we had an ambiguous tag we specialized the name(s)](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/624/how-should-we-handle-the-flash-tag). I would preferably blacklist [firmware](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/firmware) and introduce [system-firmware](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-firmware) or [device-firmware](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/device-firmware).

See also: [My answer on "Merge 'external-sd' into 'sd-card'"](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1424/440)

Comment: And alias the new tag with rom -- as system-firmware/device-firmware would refer to that?

Comment: Correct, device-firmware == rom

Comment: I agree with this. Firmware is not at all the same as ROM.

Comment: Many recommendations, but nothing happened :) Might I rise the question again: merge 'firmware' (x57) to 'radio-firmware' (x10) and synonymize? (Optionally clean-up/retag questions not related to radio-firmware first; if this path is agreed upon, I volunteer to take over that task)