# Merge 'external-sd' into 'sd-card'

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tag-cleanup

Yes, I know there are also "internal sd cards", which might cause a little confusion here. But there's no tag for them. Instead, the tag wiki for [sd-card](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sd-card) (x394) clearly reads:

> For questions related to the external micro-SD card used by most Android phones to increase the amount of available storage.

There you are. So what is the [external-sd](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/external-sd) (x8) for then -- unless we want to split things up between the two explicitly, creating an "internal-sd" tag, and arguing about "How to disambiguate the `sd-card` tag? Where should that synonym point to?" :)

I'd suggest to merge `external-sd` into `sd-card`. Whether we really need to make it a synonym after merging, I leave to the "executing mod" :)

---

As the comments raised that topic: **"What to do with questions concerning the so-called 'internal sdcard' then?"** Neither of us feels happy with that naming, but is was not us chosing it: it is not really an SDcard (in most cases, rather eMMC or the like). Despite of this,

- newer devices use `/sdcard` as mount-point for this storage, placing the "real sdcard" to `/sdcard/external_sd` or the like
- all forums, how-tos, manuals, whatever (you name it) are speaking of "internal SDCards", so a different term would cause confusion

  - terms like 'emmc-storage' would cause confusion (and might not always be "correct")
  - terms like 'flash-storage', 'phone-storage', 'device-storage', or 'internal-storage' could also apply to the area covered by `/system` (and sometimes are used referring to that explicitly, plus the latter is already used as [internal-storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internal-storage) for exactly this)

Thus, as unhappy a term it might be, this would leave [internal-sd](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internal-sd) as almost the only useful option, and we should use it (I volunteer creating it and re-tagging the questions from our current 'sd-card' tag appropriately, so the rename could be done *after* that step). If someone comes up with a better name later on, we always can rename 'internal-sd' to something more appropriate.

Comment: I'm fine with this merging (logical that `sd-card` should refer to actual SD cards), but part of me thinks that we may ultimately need an `internal-sd` (or similar) tag. Otherwise I'm not sure what else you would use to refer to the internal `/sdcard` mount point on devices that have both (e.g. the Xoom, the Galaxy S3). `internal-sd` seems icky though...maybe there's a better term.

Comment: As `internal-storage` would be ambiguous if used for that, I agree for an additional tag. All currently used storage tags are listed in the [storage tag wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/storage/info), and there is none for "internal sd". If agreed upon, I could create the `internal-sd` tag and walk through all Qs tagged "sd-card" to sort those out, report back here, and you could start the merge then?

Comment: Like I said, I'm okay with a new tag for that and I'm starting to think it may almost be necessary. If you have other ideas for naming it I'd be open to suggestions. I'm not all that enthusiastic about `internal-sd` simply because it's kind of a confusing phrasing (and it's not actually an SD card, so it could be a bit deceiving).

Comment: That's exactly what makes me hesitating (with a clear tag name in mind, I would have gone straight ahead). Unfortunately, that's what manufacturers name it (just think of `/sdcard/external_sd`, which is still confusing me). But how about this suggestion: I go ahead with 'internal-sd' for now so we can clean-up "that mess", and as soon as we find a better name for that tag we can always rename it?

Comment: @eldarerathis I just updated the question accordingly. Looks like 'internal-sd' really is the only choice left currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25/conversation/sdcard-tag it seems that a generic [sdcard](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sdcard) is usefull. So we won't merge these two.

Comment: Don't you mean the other way around? Keep `sd-card` as synonym to `external-sdcard` until it gets blacklisted (with `external-sdcard` being the master)?

Comment: As the `external-sd` tag has a `external-sdcard` synonym for autocompletion of 'sdcard', could we have the same for `internal-sd`?

Comment: OK, so I've been through all the ~400 questions tagged 'sd-card' and sorted them out. 134 are left as being "generic", 16 were specific to 'internal-sd', and 233 went to 'external-sd'. Just for the books :) If anybody is summing it up: right, some were not related to any sd-card whatever, so they've got the tag removed #)